# Create wire mesh from image

Tags: images

I am trying to create a wire mesh (the format should be POWERVR POD, but I if there is a way to convert from another format to this it's fine). However, all I have are images of the object. Is there any way to create a wire mesh from several images?

Comment: Is this 3d? If so, it's off-topic...

Comment: Not sure why 3D would be off topic.

Comment: Yes, it is 3D. I'm sorry if it is off-topic, however I wasn't able to find any other stack exchange site to ask it on.

Comment: They did trial a 3D site but it just didn't get enough action and was closed.

Comment: Filing this one under "Technical questions related to 3D software" and closing as off-topic.  If you're still looking for an answer, you may want to try [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean: "Is there any software I can feed with images and it creates a 3D model from it?"

No.

To manualy create a 3D model from any image there are several good (video) tutorials, that explain how to use images a helping tool, when creating a 3D model (e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-P2o4M-hRgA - pretty good Blender video-tut)